# Win 2k3 Connections Limit per ip:port

Tags: networking, connection, port, windows-server-2003, tcpip

I want to limit connections number per ip on specific port.
Should I use some firewall or anything else?

Advice please.

P.S. Port doesn't have to be port 80, or 3389. It can be any port

Answer (score 0):

Although its possible for more advanced firewalls to limit the number of simultaneous connections per port, this setting is usually a function of whatever server is listening on that port.  The basic Windows firewall doesn't allow this.  You might get a more specific answer if you specify what server program's connections you're trying to limit.